Magento 2.4.6-p6 Incorrect JavaScript File Path at Checkout
After upgrading Magento from version 2.4.6-p3 to 2.4.6-p6, I'm encountering an issue where JavaScript files are being loaded from incorrect paths at checkout.
In Magento 2.4.6-p6, the file is being attempted to load from:
https://baseurl.com/checkout/jquery.js
However, it should be loaded from:
https://baseurl.com/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_GB/jquery.min.js
When I switch back to version 2.4.6-p3, the correct path is used. This issue is not limited to just this file; other JavaScript files are also showing similar errors.
What could be the reason for this change in the file path after the upgrade? How can I resolve this issue to ensure that the correct paths are used in Magento 2.4.6-p6?

Delete static files
Run commands below
php bin\magento cache:clean
php bin\magento setup:upgrade
php bin\magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB


I have already done this multiple times but it does not work.

In Magento version 2.4.6-p6, Content Security Policy (CSP) is enabled by default on the checkout page, which can cause issues with the functionality of checkout. To resolve this, you need to add the following code to the etc\config.xml file in your custom module. This code configures CSP to be in "report only" mode, allowing the checkout to work as expected:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2020 Grazitti. All rights reserved.
*/
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <csp>
          <mode>
           <storefront_checkout_index_index>
           <report_only>1</report_only>
          </storefront_checkout_index_index>
       </mode>
    </csp>
 </default>
</config>

